# Civicrm Development (Coding) Environment Virtual Machine

Tags: extension

Is there a VM available for quickly and painlessly getting started with CiviCRM extension development (Wordpress) on Windows? Something that has buildkit installed. I just want to be able to get into learning extension development, on an existing environment that is read-to-go.

Answer (score 2):

There's [docker](https://github.com/michaelmcandrew/civicrm-buildkit-docker), there's [vagrant](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit-vagrant) but there isn't a pre-built VM setup.

I can probably knock something up next week if there's a demand for it (we have a local Ubuntu 18.04 BuildKit VM which we have templated for re-use.

https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/

We're also continually testing BuildKit on Windows Subsystem for Linux and this is so close to working with one issue remaining on the WSL platform which is preventing full functionality.

Comment: is it at all possible for you "knock something up" and share it with myself and the community? This would be so so so much appreciated! Please let me know?